# rijndael_128 ruby without mcrypt

Tags: ruby, encryption, jruby, mcrypt, rijndael

Hello I have next implementation of rijdael_128 encyption/decription in ruby

```
require 'mcrypt'
class Crypt

  attr_accessor :key, :iv

  def initialize(key, iv = nil)
    self.key = key
    self.iv = iv

    @enc = Mcrypt.new(:rijndael_128, :cbc, normalize_key, self.iv, :pkcs)
  end

  def encrypt(data)
    @enc.encrypt(data)
  end

  def decrypt(data)
    @enc.decrypt(data).gsub(/[^0-9#,]/, '') # clean up last \a symbols
  end

  protected
  def normalize_key

    return self.key if [16, 24, 32].include?(self.key.length)

    if self.key.length < 16
      self.key.split.pack('a16')
    elsif self.key.length < 24
      self.key.split.pack('a24')
    elsif self.key.length < 32
      self.key.split.pack('a32')
    elsif self.key.length > 32
      self.key[0..31]
    end
  end

end
```

Is there a way to implement this without mcrypt ? 
 want to use Cipher, however I have different results when key length > 16

```
class Crypt2

  attr_accessor :key, :iv

  def initialize(key, iv = nil)
    self.key = key
    self.iv = iv
  end

   def encrypt(data)
        cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-128-CBC')
        cipher.encrypt
        cipher
        cipher.key = normalize_key
        cipher.iv = self.iv
        enc =  cipher.update(data)
        enc  << cipher.final
    end

    protected
    def normalize_key

      return self.key if [16, 24, 32].include?(self.key.length)

      if self.key.length < 16
        self.key.split.pack('a16')
      elsif self.key.length < 24
        self.key.split.pack('a24')
      elsif self.key.length < 32
        self.key.split.pack('a32')
      elsif self.key.length > 32
        self.key[0..31]
      end
    end

end
```

Same results with key = "1234567890"

```
1.9.3-p547 :498 > key = "1234567890"
     => "1234567890" 
    1.9.3-p547 :499 > iv 
     => "0000001409228008" 
    1.9.3-p547 :500 > data
     => "1409227523#143620#16502300493" 
    1.9.3-p547 :501 > Crypt.new(key,iv).encrypt(data)
     => "\xFB\x16\a\xFF\x9ED\xA8\xD7\x1F=k\x8E\xFFH\xB0\x17\x84:\x1Fa\xB8s\x14\x97%S\xF3\x1E_\xDF\xBB\x19" 
    1.9.3-p547 :502 > Crypt2.new(key,iv).encrypt(data)
     => "\xFB\x16\a\xFF\x9ED\xA8\xD7\x1F=k\x8E\xFFH\xB0\x17\x84:\x1Fa\xB8s\x14\x97%S\xF3\x1E_\xDF\xBB\x19"
```

Different results with larger key

```
1.9.3-p547 :503 > key = key * 2
         => "12345678901234567890" 
        1.9.3-p547 :504 > Crypt.new(key,iv).encrypt(data)
         => "\x1A\xE61\xD7\xC8;\xE0M\xFA\xD4~[\xBA7N\xD9\xB9\xE2\x94\x8C\xA89\x99\xD9}\x82,9\xFE\xF5\xFA\x00" 
        1.9.3-p547 :505 > Crypt2.new(key,iv).encrypt(data)
         => "10X.\"\xF3\xC3RO`\t\x17\xB43\"r\x87s\xCF\xEA\x93Y4z\xCC\xC9\xAFA\xA1\x80\xC9\xF7"
```

Comment: You are explicitly initializing `AES-128`, and so the encryption function expects a *key-length* of `128 bit`.
That means, when you pass a larger key, it's behavior is undefined. (could throw an error, could shrink the key, could do encryption with the larger key, ...). It seems that `mcrypt()` and `Cipher` handle larger key differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I commented before, you are explicitly initializing `Cipher`/`mcrypt` with `AES-128`/`rijndael-128`. That means the encryption function expects a *key* with length `128 bit`/`16 bytes`.

It's behavior is undefined when you pass a larger *key*. (It could throw an error, could shrink the key, could do encryption with the larger key, or could do something else.)

It seems that `Cipher` and `mcrypt` handle this case differently and hence give different outputs.

---

**Tests:**

I could not find any statement on that case in either of the docs and so did some research on my own.
For reference, this is the test-code I used:

```
require "rubygems"
require "openssl"
require "mcrypt"

def encryptOpenSSL(iv, key, data, key_length)
    cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new("AES-" + key_length.to_s + "-CBC")
    cipher.encrypt
    cipher.key = key
    cipher.iv = iv

    return (cipher.update(data) + cipher.final).unpack("H*").join()
end

def encryptMcrypt(iv, key, data)
    cipher = Mcrypt.new(:rijndael_128, :cbc, key, iv, :pkcs)

    return cipher.encrypt(data).unpack("H*").join()
end

# test parameters
data =   "This is my test-data!"
key128 = "1234567890123456"
key256 = "1234567890123456abcdefghijklmnop"
iv  =    "0987654321098765"

# tests
puts "OpenSSL AES(128) key=128bit: " + encryptOpenSSL(iv, key128, data, 128)
puts "OpenSSL AES(128) key=256bit: " + encryptOpenSSL(iv, key256, data, 128)
puts "Mcrypt  AES(128) key=128bit: " +  encryptMcrypt(iv, key128, data)
puts "Mcrypt  AES(128) key=256bit: " +  encryptMcrypt(iv, key256, data)
puts "OpenSSL AES(256) key=256bit: " + encryptOpenSSL(iv, key256, data, 256)
```

Which outputs for me (on `ruby 1.9.1`):

```
"OpenSSL AES(128) key=128bit: adffaed8c94ede8aa61138b3fe500e30a0 ..."
"OpenSSL AES(128) key=256bit: adffaed8c94ede8aa61138b3fe500e30a0 ..."
"Mcrypt  AES(128) key=128bit: adffaed8c94ede8aa61138b3fe500e30a0 ..."
"Mcrypt  AES(128) key=256bit: b07776231d1bfbd2dfe3f8a62affdc4223 ..."
"OpenSSL AES(256) key=256bit: b07776231d1bfbd2dfe3f8a62affdc4223 ..."
```

**Conclusion:**

Looking at the test results, you can easily see that `Cipher` still uses only the first `128 bits` when you pass a larger *key* than expected.

Whereas `mcrypt()` performs `rijndael-256` encryption when you pass a `256 bit` *key* (even though you have set `rijndael-128` before).

---

**Solution:**

Assuming you want `Cipher` to encrypt with `AES-256` when you pass a `256 bit` *key*, you could dynamically set the `key_size` depending on your input `key.length`. Like this:

```
# `* 8` to convert from `bytes` to `bits`
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-' + (normalize_key.length * 8).to_s + '-CBC')
```